# Wordpress limit post that subscriber can create

Tags: wordpress

Hi my wordpress users are able to submit posts.
But I want to limit the number of posts that they can submit.
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You might try the [WordPress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) **after making sure the question is on-topic there** - check their help center.

Comment: Thanks I ask there too

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the wordpress plugin '[Bainternet Posts Creation Limits](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/)'. This will help to Limit number any post type creation by user Role.

Comment: function should be that but both this plugin both https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/wpsite-limit-posts/ doesnt work :(

Comment: is the post creating from front end?

Comment: is this functionality is for each user? or based on user role ? example  'user1' can create 10 post and 'user2' can create 15 post ?

Comment: This is my settings, so not for each user but for subscriber:

User Role: Subscriber
Post Type: Any
Limit: 2
Status: Any  
Time Span : FOREVER

Comment: only 2 posts can create by each user ?